# Speed up chown for very large codebase

Tags: command-line, chown

We have a scenario where we need to `chown <group>:<user>` on a LInux machine frequently for large sandboxes which contain thousands of directories/subdirectories, textfiles, object files, symlinks, tarballs, iso images etc.

Currently, I am using `chown -R` to recursively change ownership of everything in the sandbox and works without issues, but takes a very long time: around 10 mins.

Is there any reliable way to make recursive `chown` faster?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to speed up `chown -R`. You could try to run more than one `chown -R` on separate subdirectories in parallel or you could try `find . -exec chown group:user {} +`. This might be an XY problem. Why do you need to do this *frequently* and why do you need it to be faster? Please [edit] your question and explain your use case in more detail.